# Loop panel data using plm

Tags: r, plm

I have a df that looks like this:

```
Country  Year  X       Y1    Y2    Y3    Y4
ARG      1990  0.4875  1.23  2.51  1.42  4.85
ARG      1991  0.4952  1.66  2.31  1.25  5.02
ARG      1992  0.5120  1.87  2.57  1.92  4.66
ARG      1993  0.5213  1.96  2.41  2.42  5.85
```

Where X is my independent variable and Ys are the dependent variables I want to loop on.

I tried something like:

```
for (i in out_start:out_end){
  outcome = colnames(RegTest)[i]
  model <- plm(get(outcome) ~ X, data=RegTest, index=c("Country", "year"), model= "within")
  summary(model)
}
```

Where I previously set out_start at 4 and end at the end of my columns but I get an error message saying:

```
Error in uniqval[as.character(effect), , drop = F] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

I can't see what is wrong since it seems to get correctly the name of the column.

PS: if someone knows also how to list all summaries in one df it would be super helpful.

Comment: Would need further details for help. But it seems that you don't have unique values for your country effect.  Look for country year duplicates. Forget about the loop and try directly first. Then use the loop.

Answer (score 1):

For solving the issue with the formula You could use the `paste()` function in conjunction with `as.formula()`.

It is fairly easy to save the results produced by each call of `summary()` in a list. You could initialize `model` as a `list` before the loop and assign the outcome from each iteration of the loop as an entry to `model`.

The following code chunk demonstrates how to do this using the dataset `Fatalities` from package `AER`. I chose `miles` as the regressor and the loop runs over several measures of traffic fatalities.

```
library(AER)
library(plm)
data("Fatalities")

out_start <- 17
out_end <- 26

model <- list()

for (i in out_start:out_end){
  outcome <- colnames(Fatalities)[i]
  model[[i-out_start+1]] <- summary(
    plm(as.formula(paste(outcome, " ~ miles", sep = "")), 
        data = Fatalities, 
        index=c("state", "year"), model= "within") 
  )
}
model
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the following packages

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plm)
library(broom)
```

Let's creat your data set: beware, I think the error message depends on "Country" variable which needs more than one value to run the model.

```
RegTest <- data.frame(rep(c("ARG","SPA"),2),
                      c(1990,1990,1991,1991),
                      c(0.4875,0.4952,0.5120,0.5213),
                      c(1.23,1.66,1.87,1.96),
                      c(2.51,2.31,2.57,2.41),
                      c(1.42,1.25,1.92,2.42),
                      c(4.85,5.02,4.66,5.85))
names(RegTest) <- c("Country","Year","X","Y1","Y2","Y3","Y4")
```

Pick up the indipendent variables from the original dataset

```
indipendent_variables <- RegTest[,4:7]
```

Build a function with your model, setting `indipendet_variables` like the main argument of the function

```
plm_function <- function(indipendent_variable) 
    plm(indipendent_variables ~ X, data=RegTest, index=c("Country","Year"), model="within")
```

Let's use `map` function from purrr package to run iteratively your function without using for loops

```
models <- map(indipendent_variables, plm_function)
```

Inspect model results using `tidy` function from broom package

```
tidy(models$Y1)
```

To get more statistics from model results use `augment` function from broom package

```
tidy(augment(models$Y1))
```

Save augmented results in a dataframe

```
results_Y1 <- tidy(augment(models$Y1))
```